# How to find annotated methods in TypeElement?

Tags: java, annotation-processing

Assume that I have this class:

```
public class MyClass extends Ancestor{

    @MyAnnotation
    void doSomething(){
    }

    @MyAnnotation
    void doAnotherthing(String[] args){
    }

}

public class Ancestor{

    @MyAnnotation
    void doFirst(){
    }
}
```

In my annotation processor I have a `TypeElement` instance of `MyClass`.

How can I find annotated methods with `@MyAnnotation` in both `MyClass` and its ancestor?

( I know it's possible with `RoundEnvironment` but i don't want to use it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
static Set<Element> getAnnotatedElements(
    Elements elements,
    TypeElement type,
    Class<? extends Annotation> annotation)
{
    Set<Element> found = new HashSet<Element>();
    for (Element e : elements.getAllMembers(type)) {
        if (e.getAnnotation(annotation) != null)
            found.add(e);
    }
    return found;
}
```

Of course, you could also filter for e.g. only methods with `e.getKind() == ElementKind.METHOD`.

`Elements` is necessary because you want to find the method on the superclass as well. It's possible to do without it, but it's really much more work than necessary.

See [`Elements#getAllMembers`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/util/Elements.html#getAllMembers-javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement-), [`Element#getAnnotation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/Element.html#getAnnotation-java.lang.Class-) and also [`TypeElement#getEnclosedElements`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/TypeElement.html#getEnclosedElements--).

> I know it's possible with RoundEnvironment but i don't want to use it

From the documentation for [`RoundEnvironment#getElementsAnnotatedWith`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/RoundEnvironment.html#getElementsAnnotatedWith-java.lang.Class-):

> Only package elements and type elements ***included* in this round of annotation processing**, or declarations of members, constructors, parameters, or type parameters declared within those, are returned.

So actually, `RoundEnvironment` may or may not work for finding annotated elements in general, depending on what you're doing. The methods on `RoundEnvironment` are *specifically* useful for finding the elements which are annotated with the annotation you are processing.

Also of course it's pretty terrible if you want to reduce the search to some smaller scope, in your case, `MyClass`. `RoundEnvironment` finds *everything*. If we wanted to, say, find methods that some particular class `Bar` overrides from its superclass `Foo`, `RoundEnvironment` is very awkward for that. We'd have to find *all* methods that override anything, then use `getEnclosingElement()` to find the ones that belong to `Bar`.

If, for example, you were writing an annotation processor *for `MyAnnotation`*, then it would make much more sense to use `RoundEnvironment`, because annotations are not necessarily processed in a single round. Searching for annotations yourself instead of going through `RoundEnvironment` could result in you finding annotations that you've already processed on a prior round.

Answer (score 0):

If you writing annotation processor you have to use RoundEnvironment. That is how annotation processors are working. Keep in mind that javac might run you several times according to it's internal needs